How to optimize chained multiple joins in pyspark
It is almost taking days to run, and not even running
df = (
        a
        .join(b, on='aa', how='left')
        .join(c, on='aa', how='left')
        .join(d, on='aa', how='left')
        .join(e, on='bb', how='left')
        .join(f, on='cc', how='left')
        .join(g, on='dd', how='left')
    )    

number of rows for dataframe
a: 3500000
b: 85000000
c: 420000
d: 2200000
e: 30000
f: 20000
g: 60000

DAG



Understand your data and try to filter out records before joining.



If a dataframe is small, go for broadcast join.



If it is big, Try to store the data by partitioning it based on the join keys. Then read this partitioned data for joining.


@ArudSekaBerneS in my scenario, we don't have any filter before joining, and possibly you are already aware of no. of rows which i have in tables, so that also cannot be changed. and we have to run this in run time, so storing is also intuitive

One more tip. Materialize the join and see if it helps. My jobs used to hang on long complicated transformations.
df.count() doesn't materialize the dataframe.  To see this, materialize the dataframe with. df.cache.foreach(lambda x: x) and then df.count(), now the count won't printed immediately. Having long lineage of transformations slows down final evaluation so it takes more time. After every Nth transformation (N = 2 or 3 or 4) materialize the dataframe. Try this workaround if it works.

Every Spark dataframe has RDD internally, we can use it to optimize the query.
you can try joining the tables using RDD, based on above given example.
Convert each tables into Pair RDD on column you want to join
pair_a = a.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x)) # pair("aa", Row(Record))
pair_b = b.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x)) # pair("aa", Row(Record))
pair_c = c.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x)) # pair("aa", Row(Record))
pair_d = d.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x)) # pair("aa", Row(Record))

Join on aa column
join_aa_pair = pair_a.leftOuterJoin(pair_b).leftOuterJoin(pair_c).leftOuterJoin(pair_d)
# ('aa104', (((Row(aa='aa104', name='name:104'), bb123), cc11), dd212)) =>  ('aa104', 'name:104', 'bb123', 'cc11', 'dd212')
transform_aa_pair = join_aa_pair.map(lambda x : (x[1][0][0][0].aa, x[1][0][0][0].name, checkNoneBB(x[1][0][0][1]), checkNoneCC(x[1][0][1]), checkNoneDD(x[1][1])))

def checkNoneBB(x):
    if x is not None:
       return ""+x.bb
    else:
       return "bbNone"

Convert another tables to pairRDD
pair_e = e.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x)) # pair("bb", Row(Record))
pair_f = f.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x)) # pair("cc", Row(Record))
pair_g = g.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x)) # pair("dd", Row(Record))

Transform the RDD to Pair RDD of bb column
bb_transform_pair = transform_aa_pair.map(lambda x: (x[2], x)) # pair("bb", Row(Record))
bb_join_pair = bb_transform_pair.leftOuterJoin(pair_e) # left join on bb

Transform the RDD to Pair RDD of cc column
cc_transform_pair = bb_join_pair.map(lambda x: (x[1][0][3], x[1])) # create pair("cc", Row(Record))
cc_join_pair = cc_transform_pair.leftOuterJoin(pair_f) # left join on cc

Transform the RDD to Pair RDD of dd column
dd_transform_pair = cc_join_pair.map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0][4], x[1][0][0])) # create pair("dd", Row(Record))
dd_join_pair = dd_transform_pair.leftOuterJoin(pair_g) # left join on dd
dd_join_pair.cache()
dd_join_pair.count()

dd_join_pair will contains joins attributes from all columns. Transform into proper Row Records for your column, Provide a Schema to convert back to spark sql dataframe.
df = spark.createDataFrame(dd_join_pair, schema=schema)

It is an optimize way of join using RDD.
Recommendation: Avoid using all the data for analysis try to filter out unnecessary data and reduce the data size.

Thanks for your detailed explanation, Let me try

While I am trying, I am trying to understand, what is "bb" mean in this code....def checkNoneBB(x):
if x is not None:
return ""+x.bb
else:
return "bbNone"

I tried, with sample of .01 percent of original data, but .cache() part and leftOuterJoin part is halting for bigger data

bb is the any column you need extract after the join, there are multiple columns need to be extracted, you need different python function for each column and "bbNone" is a string for None values.
if .cache() not working you may not have enough memory to do the compute.
cache() will cache your existing processing till you call the cache() and save recomputing.

if are running once try removing the cache method.
try calling the repartition before cache dd_join_pair.repartition(dd_join_pair.getNumPartitions()*3)
try increasing the memory of the cluster by adding nodes


Thanks for educating, I tried with 16 C, 64 GB M, x8 worker, x1 driver of same spec, it it is a rather powerfull compute
